# Executing roles based on variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm having some odd behavior.  I'm still an Ansible novice, so I apologize in advance.

I'm trying to conditionally execute a role, based on an example I saw here: https://github.com/atomicobject/ansible-laptop-playbook-example/blob/1785f25014fa5a7776de5b332d093b60bf59c8e0/laptop.yml

Anyway, I have a `host_vars/localhost`:

```
has_thing: true
```

In my top-level `site.yml`, I have:

```
  -name: Title
   hosts: all

   roles:
     - { role: myrole, when: has_thing is defined and has_thing == "true" }
```

This skips the role.

If I do this instead:

```
  -name: Title
   hosts: all

   roles:
     - { role: myrole, when: has_thing is defined }
```

the role executes.

If I do this:

```
  -name: Title
   hosts: all

   roles:
     - { role: myrole, when: has_thing == "true" }
```

It does not work.

If I do:

```
  -name: Title
   hosts: all

   roles:
     - { role: myrole, when: has_thing != "true" }
```

It still does not work.  I don't understand why, the variables `has_thing` is clearly defined because it works as long as I don't test its value.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_thing: true` is a boolean, you may test with `has_thing: 'true'`.

But better change your `when` statement to handle boolean values.

P.S. And you can't *conditionally execute a role* a role this way, role will be always executed, but the `when` statement will be appended to every task in this role generating a lot of skipped tasks in the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot Konstantin.  I tried to do `- { role: myrole, when: has_thing is defined and has_thing: 'true' }` but got an error about syntax on the `has_thing: 'true' }`.  Any idea why?

Comment: Use `debug: var=has_thing`, quoted output mean string, not quoted - other types. Something like `when: has_thing | default(false) | bool` should do what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the ninja edit.  I understand what you are saying now.  Thanks a lot for your help.